# AJAX functionality nopt working in IE 7 nad IE 8

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am facing a problem that my AJAX functionality is working fine in Chrome, Firefox and also IE 9, but not working in IE 7 and IE 8.

This is my AJAX code.

```
var url = 'abcd.php';
var dataString = '&id='+id+'&type=mesg';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    global: true,
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg)
       {
       alert(msg);
           $('#main_data').html(msg);
       }
    });
```

It works fine until the `alert` msg, but does not display any output.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you show the relevant html?

Comment: this is my HTML code:
 <td width="80%" align="left" valign="top" id="main_data">

Comment: Can you post your full HTML code, that might help a bit more.

Comment: my code is of 1200 lines. can i mail to you

Comment: Check that you have unique `id` `main_data` in you `1200 lines page`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `jquery version 2+` which doesn't supports `< IE 9`

**No more support for IE 6/7/8:** `Remember that this can also affect IE9 and even IE10 if they are used in their “Compatibility View” modes that emulate older versions. To prevent these newer IE versions from slipping back into prehistoric modes, we suggest you always use an X-UA-Compatible tag or HTTP header. If you can use the HTTP header it is slightly better for performance because it avoids a potential browser parser restart.`

Read [jquery-2-0-released](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)

So, you should use `jquery version 1.9 for older versions of IE like IE 6,7,8`
or you can add this to your `html page`

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<script src="jquery-2.0.0.js"><</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I have change the jquery version 1.9 but still the problem remains the same

Comment: but actually i am using jquery-1.6.1

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$.support.cors= true;
var url = 'abcd.php';
var dataString = '&id='+id+'&type=mesg';
$.ajax({
async: false,
url: url,
global: true,
type: "POST",
data: dataString,
dataType: "html",
success: function(msg)
   {
   alert(msg);
       $('#main_data').html(msg);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using UTF-8 to encode the AJAX response, IE can not determine it automatically, besides it will throw an exception: "System error 1072896658".

[image: AJAX but in IE]

See also for detailed information: http://keelypavan.blogspot.com/2006/07/system-error-1072896658-in-ie.html

Then here comes a solution. You should add a HTTP header in abcd.php to declare the encoding.

e.g.

```
<?php

//... do something
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo $resonse_text;
```

Comment: where should i add this code in Ajax function or in Ajax output

Comment: @Delta oh gosh. Did your console (Press F12 to enable) tell any detail?